Why sound disappears in Tone.js with function sampler.triggerAttackRelease()
I copy paste the code on Tone.js main page:https://tonejs.github.io/
called Tone.Sampler, and just added the time and velocity to function sampler.triggerAttackRelease(). But after a few clicks, there is no more sound. Do you know why?
It works if I simply write sampler.triggerAttackRelease(["Eb4", "G4", "Bb4"], 4); but later I would like to add some specific velocity.
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>  
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Simple HTML</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <!-- LOAD Tone.js from unpkg -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/tone"></script>
        

        <script>
            // Créer le sampler une seule fois à l'extérieur de la fonction playSample
            const sampler = new Tone.Sampler({
                urls: { //-- liste des fichiers disponibles et notes associées
                    C4: "C4.mp3",
                    "D#4": "Ds4.mp3",
                    "F#4": "Fs4.mp3",
                    A4: "A4.mp3",
                },
                release: 1,
                baseUrl: "https://tonejs.github.io/audio/salamander/",
            }).toDestination();


            function playSample() 
            {
                // Vérification que Tone.js est prêt et démarre le contexte si nécessaire
                if (Tone.context.state !== 'running') 
                {
                    Tone.start(); // Démarre le contexte de son si ce n'est pas déjà fait
                }
                
                Tone.loaded().then(() => 
                {
                sampler.triggerAttackRelease(["Eb4", "G4", "Bb4"], 4, 0, 0.1); // notes, duration, time, velocity
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <h1>Un accord répété, Demo</h1>
        <button onclick="playSample()">Click me to play sample note!</button>
    </body>
</html>


This is a scheduling problem, you do not want the "time" fixed to 0, rather you need to adapt the time to the audiocontext transport.
You can view it like in a DAW, when you click the play button.
For example, after Tone start, when you click your button again, say 3sec later, you should replace 0 by 0 + 3.
In your code, you can change 0 by Tone.now(), it will work.
sampler.triggerAttackRelease(["Eb4", "G4", "Bb4"], 4, Tone.now(), 0.1);

See this answer or this one for better explanation.
